# How can I check a checkbox in Python's Tkinter grid

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, checkbox, tkinter

I have a checkbox on a GUI, using the following script:

```
# Define checkbox
CheckVar1 = IntVar()
C1 = Checkbutton(tab2, text = "NW", variable = CheckVar1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)

# Place checkbox on GUI
C1.grid(column=0, row=4)
```

What command can I use to check the box, if a certain condition is met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `set` method of the associated varible:

```
CheckVar1.set(1)
```